# How to translate text in c#?

Tags: json, .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0

How can I translate a string in english to spanish in c#?

```
string bio="my name is xyz";
```

I made a culture to convert the string:

```
string bio = "my name is xyz";
var culture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
Console.WriteLine(name.ToString(culture));
```

Comment: No, there is no built-in way to translate random texts

Comment: C# has no such feature. It doesn't translate text by itself. You need specific libraries like those for Google Translate or ChatGPT

Comment: You can use [resource files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/create-resource-files) to store texts that you translated yourself